# WooCommerce execute function if product is from a certain category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I'm trying to translate my products in WooCommerce based on the category.

When WooCommerce is loaded, I run an action hook:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'translate_products' );`

In my function translate_products I run a WP_Query so I can translate the products based on the current ID of the loop. It only translates all products, not only the ones with the category 'en' though. I am unable to get only the ID of the products assigned to the 'en' category.

It would be more than great, if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

I'm fairly new to Wordpress and especially WooCommerce coding, so please excuse me, if I'm doing a stupid mistake. ;)

Here's my code:

```
function translate_products() {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'product_cat' => 'en' );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

        global $product;    
        $current_id = get_the_id();
        pll_set_post_language($current_id,'en');

    endwhile; 

    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use own function for fetch WooCommerce product is not good idea of wordpress programming.

Please read official document of WooCommerce. Open the link and find "Product Categories".

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

If you want to use category name of that product then you have to find its term id and use id and use in shortcode

Comment: Are you saying that I can fatch a products array like this? 
`$products => [product_categories number="12" parent="0" ids="$my_id"]`
Thanks

Comment: You can write ids with comma separated

[product_categories ids="12,15,16"]

Comment: [product_categories] called as shortcode in wordpress. 

=> You can use in back end just write "[product_categories]"

=> You can use in text editor help of "do_Shortcode()"

https://codex.wordpress.org/it:Riferimento_funzioni/do_shortcode

Comment: Is my suggestion is useful for you?